# Prove that the function proves this equality

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have to prove that this function:

[image: function]

proves the equality:

[image: equality]

I really need your help, because I don't know how to make the partial derivatives of the function u. I'm not sure if I'm right here:

[image: partial derivative]

So, please help me by giving a hint or whatever on how can I find the partial derivatives of this function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That partial derivative is not correct, you'll need the chain and product rules.

Comment: I really suck at partial derivatives

Comment: Elaborating on EHH's point, if you let $g(x) = F(z/x, y/x)$ then $u(x) = x^{\alpha}g(x)$ and you can use the product rule to add an important term to your $du/dx$ expression.  The main theory is this $$ h(t)=r(t)s(t) \implies h'(t) = r'(t)s(t)+r(t)s'(t)$$ and $$ v(t) = M(r(t),s(t)) \implies v'(t) = \frac{\partial M}{\partial x}r'(t) + \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} s'(t)$$

Comment: @snitchben Don't be too hard on yourself, there is lots to learn with partial derivatives and you'll pick it up with practice, the right way to go about it is to do lots of examples and ask for help when you get stuck as you have done. Everyone has to go through this learning curve so we all know what it's like. Just keep at it and you'll do fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to see the function $F$ as a composite function $F(v,w)$ with $v=\frac{z}{x}$ and $w=\frac{y}{x}$. Now we can use the chain rule to evaluate the derivative:
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\left(\frac{-z}{x^2}\right)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}\left(\frac{-y}{x^2}\right)
$$ 
and , with the product rule:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}F(v,w)+x^{\alpha}\left[ \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\left(\frac{-z}{x^2}\right)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}\left(\frac{-y}{x^2}\right)\right]=
x^{\alpha-1}\left[\alpha F(v,w) -\frac{1}{x}\left(  z\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}+y\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}  \right)  \right]
$$

Now you can do the same with the other derivative and verify the given. equality